# Android WebView Uncaught Reference Error

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have a simple WebView in my app that loads the Google Finance page with a specific symbol so users can see historical prices and other information, but for some reason in the Log I keep seeing this message when loading the webview:

```
I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(242)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: og is not defined", source: https://www.google.com/m/finance#search/GOOG (242)
```

Although this doesn't prevent the webview from loading the url, I don't understand why I'm getting that message. I've tried with numerous ticker symbols (for example replace GOOG with AXP, BUD, CMCSK) and the message is always the same so I'm thinking it's referring to the "google" part of the url but I don't know why it would come up as not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simply a javascript error that happened on the specific page you loaded.

Try loading the page:

https://www.google.com/m/finance#search/GOOG

in browser with opened developer console and you will see something like this:

[image]

==> as long as you do not control the webpage you are loading there is not much what you can do about that. Except maybe checking if the url etc. that you use is the right one.

Comment: Thanks, just wasn't sure if it was something I was doing but since I'm just loading the page it should be fine